# Accessing subdomain redirects to main domain

Tags: subdomain, https, top-level-domains, iis

I have primary domain (https://example.com) and subdomain (http://subdomain.example.com). I have domain-level SSL certificate installed for primary domain (TLD). And I want access my subdomain via HTTP not HTTPS (I don't want to buy another SSL for subdomain because it is for testing purpsoses). But accessing subdomain always redirects to TLD and address bar remains as `https://sudomain.example.com` but actually requesting main site `https://example.com`.
So, even if I type `http://subdomain.example.com` I'm forcebly redirected to `https://subdomain.example.com` seeing content of `https://example.com`.

How to avoid this redirection and get my subdomain site work?

Tech. specs: IIS 8.5, ASP.NET MVC 5, hosting space (arvixe.com)

Comment: I do not know IIS anymore- it has been well over a decade, but this has to be a setting issue. I will up-vote this question to get you some attention. But we will need more information on your set-up, though I am not sure what we would need to give guidelines.

Comment: @closetnoc, thank you for support. Yes, it is configuration issue. The thing is I should create A-record in DNS settings of TLD. That A-record should map to shared hoster IP not to TLD IP and should contain subdomain part, for eg. `subdomain A 198.58.80.160`. I think it is an answer but I shy to answer my own question.

Comment: Hey! If it answers *your question*, then that is the answer. I encourage you to answer the question if/when you are sure it worked and then ping me- I will up-vote it!! Jump in. The water is warm! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It was configuration issue. The thing is I should create A-record in DNS settings of TLD. That A-record should map to shared hoster IP not to TLD IP and should contain subdomain part, for eg. subdomain A 198.58.80.160.